# TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm creating a mute command but when I want to disable speaking permission for the Mute role for each channel, I get this error:

> TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function

(The messages are in French)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const ms = require('ms');

module.exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {
    if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("❌ Vous n'avez pas la permission d'utiliser cette commande !");
    if(message.mentions.users.size === 0) {
        return message.channel.send("❌ Vous devez mentionner un utilisateur !");
    }
    let mute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
    if(!mute) {
        return message.channel.send("❌ L'utilisateur est introuvable !");
    }
    let muteRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Mute")
    if(!muteRole) return message.channel.send("❌ Le rôle Mute n'existe pas")
    muteRole.permissions.remove('SEND_MESSAGES', 'ADD_REACTIONS');
    let mutetime = args[1];
    if(!mutetime) return message.channel.send("❌ Vous devez spécifier un temps !");
    message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
            ATTACH_FILES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false
        })
    })
    await(mute.roles.add(muteRole.id));
    message.delete();
    message.channel.send("✅ <@" + mute + "> a bien été muté pendant " + mutetime);

    setTimeout(function() {
        mute.roles.remove(muteRole.id);
        message.channel.send()
    }, ms(mutetime));
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "mute"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Discord.js v12, it is `message.guild.channels.cache`.
Also, get rid of the `id` parameter, I don't know what you need that for.
Should look like this:

```js
 message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(async channel => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
            ATTACH_FILES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't how to explain it, but it doesn't pass on an ID.

```
 message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muteRole, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: false,
            ATTACH_FILES: false,
            ADD_REACTIONS: false
        })
    })
```

Should work if you just do

```
.forEach(async (channel, id) => { 
});
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Thank you but I can't understand, where do I put this??
Because my code is not different

Comment: Oh, intead of what you already put haha. But I'll suggest making a try function and catch errors, I found that way to work the best. Something close to this

  if (!muterole) {
    try {
      muterole = await message.guild.createRole({
        name: " Muted",
        permissions:[]
      });
      message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel) => {
        await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
          SEND_MESSAGES: false,
          ADD_REACTIONS: false,
          SPEAK: false
        });
      });
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

Comment: Hope it makes sense!

Comment: I have test and the response is the same "message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function"