# TypeError: message.guild.channels.forEach is not a functionl

Tags: node.js, discord

i would like to make a Discord bot but i got stucked in here. Heres my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('xxx');


client.on('message', message =>{
if(message.author.id == "xxx") {
if(message.content === "!bye") {
message.guild.channels.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
  }
}
})
```

It says:

> message.guild.channels.forEach is not a function

I would like to know why is it say to me. (Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Hello Becike, and welcome to SO. Your question has the same title as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852093/typeerror-message-guild-channels-foreach-is-not-a-function), which has already some discussion on it. Please go and have a look

Comment: Hey, thank you.
Yea i was see, but i didn't found the right solution for it.
And i searched all of same type of problems as mine.

Comment: Hi, I am not use to Discord APIs. But I think the value of message.guild.channels is not of type array. Can you confirm the value of message.guild.channels? You can try console.log(message.guild.channels) or Logger.info(message.guild.channels) in order to fetch the value.

Comment: Thank you @Cipher it's finally works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In discord 12, you need use new class [`channelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager)

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('xxx');


client.on('message', message =>{
if(message.author.id == "xxx") {
    if(message.content === "!bye") {
        message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.delete())
      }
    }
})
```